# CentOS 6 - chrony - No suitable source for synchronisation

Tags: ntpdate

NTP servers are available on ports 123/313

```
nc -v -u -z -w 3 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org 123
Connection to 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org 123 port [udp/ntp] succeeded!
nc -v -u -z -w 3 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org 123
Connection to 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org 123 port [udp/ntp] succeeded!
nc -v -u -z -w 3 3.rhel.pool.ntp.org 123
Connection to 3.rhel.pool.ntp.org 123 port [udp/ntp] succeeded!
nc -v -u -z -w 3 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313
Connection to 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313 port [udp/magenta-logic] succeeded!
nc -v -u -z -w 3 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313
Connection to 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313 port [udp/magenta-logic] succeeded!
nc -v -u -z -w 3 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313
Connection to 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313 port [udp/magenta-logic] succeeded!
nc -v -u -z -w 3 3.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313
Connection to 3.rhel.pool.ntp.org 313 port [udp/magenta-logic] succeeded

 ntpdate -d server 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org
26 Sep 07:31:23 ntpdate[17394]: ntpdate 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Wed Dec 19 20:22:35 UTC 2018 (1)
Looking for host server and service ntp
Error resolving server: Name or service not known (-2)
26 Sep 07:31:23 ntpdate[17394]: Can't find host server: Name or service not known (-2)
Looking for host 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org and service ntp
host found : time.vedur.is
transmit(130.208.87.151)
transmit(193.4.58.77)
transmit(130.208.87.151)
transmit(193.4.58.77)
transmit(130.208.87.151)
transmit(193.4.58.77)
transmit(130.208.87.151)
transmit(193.4.58.77)
transmit(130.208.87.151)
transmit(193.4.58.77)
130.208.87.151: Server dropped: no data
193.4.58.77: Server dropped: no data
server 130.208.87.151, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [130.208.87.151], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 22:32:12.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 22:32:12.000
transmit timestamp:  e6dbd3ce.54b42604  Mon, Sep 26 2022  7:31:26.330
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

server 193.4.58.77, port 123
stratum 0, precision 0, leap 00, trust 000
refid [193.4.58.77], delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
transmitted 4, in filter 4
reference time:    00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 22:32:12.000
originate timestamp: 00000000.00000000  Sun, Dec 31 1899 22:32:12.000
transmit timestamp:  e6dbd3ce.87e7ac7b  Mon, Sep 26 2022  7:31:26.530
filter delay:  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
         0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000
filter offset: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
         0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
delay 0.00000, dispersion 64.00000
offset 0.000000

26 Sep 07:31:27 ntpdate[17394]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

chrony.conf file:

```
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
server 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.rhel.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Ignore stratum in source selection.
stratumweight 0

# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# In first three updates step the system clock instead of slew
# if the adjustment is larger than 10 seconds.
makestep 1.0 3

# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync

# Allow NTP client access from local network.
# allow 192.168.10/24

# Serve time even if not synchronized to any NTP server.
#local stratum 10

# Specify file containing keys for NTP and command authentication.
#keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

# Specify key number for command authentication.
commandkey 1

# Generate new command key on start if missing.
generatecommandkey

minsources 3

# Disable logging of client accesses.
noclientlog

# Send message to syslog when clock adjustment is larger than 0.5 seconds.
logchange 0.5

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Select which information is logged.
log measurements statistics tracking
```

iptables are off

Comment: Read the man page again, it's `ntpdate -d 1.rhel.pool.ntp.org`. `server` is in italics meaning replace with host. It was also able to connect to `193.4.58.77`. As to why it does not sync, I would first try dropping the version number via `-o`, and run `tcpdump` on port `123` and inspect what is going across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Incoming traffic from Internet NTP servers on port 123 was blocked.
After network department opened incoming traffic to local server, was able to sync time.